# numpy: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` with `in` statement

Tags: python, numpy, comparison, warnings, future

I am reading via a given library from hardware. I may either get a numpy array or - in case of an error in the hardware - a `None`.

I want to check for the `None`'s and skip events that contain them:

```
for event in hardware.events():
    val1 = event.get_first_value()
    val2 = event.get_second_value()
    #potentially more of the above

    if None in (val1, val2):
        continue
```

I always thought this was the cleanest way to do this test. In particular, when there are many more values to compare. However, I just got this FutureWarning for doing so:

```
FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
```

I understand this comes from a [change](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2014-September/071235.html) in how numpy handles equality (`==`) comparisons. I also understand the reasoning behind it...

A solution is obviously to do this:

```
    if val1 is None or val2 is None:
        continue
```

This will however, be looking ugly very fast, when I extend the list of vali's beyond i=2 ...

- Thus, I wonder whether this change actually applies to the `in` statement as in my example? Will I see the test yield wrong results? As far as I understand `in` anyway tests for both equality (`==`) and identity (`is`) for each element. Also, is there a performance change introduced by numpy's new elementwise check?
- And if it actually changes the result, is there another concise way of performing the same test? (An answer to this might will be useful even when my original test will never fail, simply to get rid of the FutureWarning message...)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np

# Some fake data
vals = (np.zeros(5), None)

# Test whether data contains None
if any(x is None for x in vals):
    # Do stuff
```

Comment: This is admittedly concise - upvoted for that! Still, the legibility of the original is lost ... Also, you didn't answer my questions about changes in the result and performance. Any idea about that?

Comment: I don't know how NumPy's future change will affect behavior/performance in this case. Could ask on the NumPy mailing list.